# Unauthorized when trying to use ajax with ASP.MVC CORE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application with multiple users. In one of my View I have a table which has a delete button. That button must delete the entire row.

I could use something like that on a button:

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
```

However, I was reading that it's a bad way of doing it, since when modifying resource on a server  POST must be used. Using Form tag does not seem like an option since I can have 100 or 200 rows. Am I wrong?

That is why I tried to use an AJAX so that when a button is clicked it's posting in a background. That however, also gives me a lot of problems. Sometimes I ran into Unauthorized response from the server. I am using Identity framework.

I've been breaking my head for the past week trying to find a solution. I read that tokens could be used for authentication, however, it does seem like an overkill for such a simple problem. Thank you for help

Server side:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllWorkOrders()
    {
        var UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        var allWorkOrders = _context.UserHistoryDTI.Include(_ => _.WorkOrdersHistory).Where(_ => _.UserId == UserId).FirstOrDefault().WorkOrdersHistory;
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allWorkOrders));
    }
```

Client side:

```
function GetWorkOrderList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/DTClocking/api/myhours/GetAllWorkOrders',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var objData = JSON.parse(data);
            var option = "<option>All</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
                option += '<option>' + objData[i].Name + '</option>';
            }

            $("#workOrderListDTI").empty();
            $("#workOrderListDTI").append(option);
        }
    });
}
```

When I tested locally there is no issue with authentication at all. The only time when the issue starts to occur is when I am trying to reach the website from a computer (on our local network). To make things worse, the issue is inconsistent sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Comment: You don't need to use tokens if you are using simple cookie based authentication. There may be something wrong with authentication cookie expiration.

Comment: Use of POST (or PUT or DELETE) to perform this kind of operation is a convention based thing. It's often a good idea, and it makes more semantic sense, but there's nothing which says you _must_ use it, or that you can't use GET if you wish to. Equally there's nothing to stop you having 100 or more form tags if you want to. It increases the amount of markup slightly, but doesn't really cause any other kind of problem.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It does not really go well with the ViewModel thing. I thought that the ViewModel for the view is static. If I have a table with changing rows ViewModel is changing all the time. Why is it so hard to use ajax ?

Comment: "If I have a table with changing rows ViewModel is changing all the time". I have no idea what you really mean by this, sorry, or why it would constitute a problem. Why would changing the number of rows in the table cause you to need to change your viewmodel (which, as I understand it, is a C# class)? There's nothing wrong with using ajax for this if you want to, but if you want to get your authentication issues sorted with that then you'd have to show us your ajax code and your auth setup / config.